# How can I make this code work for expiry date TextInput which includes (mm/yy) model?

Tags: react-native, react-native-ios, native-base

I want to create a checkout form which includes expiry date `TextInput`. It will look like a this (MM/YY). After adding first 2 digits it will automatically add / then the person can type last 2 digits for the year. I found this code on the other question. But it doesn't work. When you type inside the form nothing is typed. Here is the code. How can I make this code work as needed?

```
constructor() {
  super()
  this.state = {
    isReady: false
  }
}

componentDidMount() {
  this.setState({
    isReady: true
  })
}
onChange(text) {
    let newText = '';
    let numbers = '0123456789';

    for (var i = 0; i < text.length; i++) {
        if ( numbers.indexOf(text[i]) > -1 ) {
            newText = newText + text[i];
        }
    }
    this.setState({myNumber: newText})
}
formatFunction(cardExpiry = ""){
   //expiryDate will be in the format MMYY, so don't make it smart just format according to these requirements, if the input has less than 2 character return it otherwise append `/` character between 2nd and 3rd letter of the input.
   if(cardExpiry.length < 2){
    return cardExpiry;
   }
   else{
    return cardExpiry.substr(0, 2) + "/" + (cardExpiry.substr(2) || "")
   }
}

inputToValue(inputText){
    //if the input has more than 5 characters don't set the state
    if(inputText.length < 6){
         const tokens = inputText.split("/");
         // don't set the state if there is more than one "/" character in the given input
         if(tokens.length < 3){
            const month = Number(tokens[1]);
            const year = Number(tokens[2]);
            //don't set the state if the first two letter is not a valid month
            if(month >= 1 && month <= 12){
               let cardExpiry = month + "";
               //I used lodash for padding the month and year with  zero
               if(month > 1 || tokens.length === 2){
                    // user entered 2 for the month so pad it automatically or entered "1/" convert it to 01 automatically
                    cardExpiry = _.padStart(month, 2, "0");
               }
               //disregard changes for invalid years
               if(year > 1 && year <= 99){
                   cardExpiry += year;
               }
               this.setState({cardExpiry});
            }
         }
    }
}

render (){
   let {cardExpiry} = this.state;
  return (
    <Image style={styles.image} source={require('../img/cover.jpg')}
  >


         <Content style={styles.content}>

            <Form>
              <Item >
                <Icon active name='card'/>
                <Input keyboardType='numeric' maxLength={16} placeholder='Card Number'
                onChangeText = {(text)=> this.onChange(text)}
      value = {this.state.myNumber}/>
      </Item>

      <Grid>
      <Row>
      <Col>

              <Item style={{ marginBottom:10}}>
                <Icon active name='calendar' />
                <Input keyboardType='numeric' placeholder='MM/YY' 
                value = {this.formatFunction(cardExpiry)}
       onChangeText={this.inputToValue.bind(this)}/>
              </Item>
              </Col>
              <Col>

                      <Item style={{ marginBottom:10}}>
                        <Icon active name='lock' />
                        <Input maxLength={3} secureTextEntry={true}  placeholder='CVV'/>
                      </Item>
                      </Col>
              </Row>
              </Grid>
```

Comment: All these options are more or less okay but they worked very slowly for me, I prefer to use react-native-text-input-mask instead

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use this code to handle your problem:

```
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { text: '' };
  }

  handleChange = (text) => {
    let textTemp = text;
    if (textTemp[0] !== '1' && textTemp[0] !== '0') {
      textTemp = '';
    }
    if (textTemp.length === 2) {
      if (parseInt(textTemp.substring(0, 2)) > 12 || parseInt(textTemp.substring(0, 2)) == 0) {
        textTemp = textTemp[0];
      } else if (this.state.text.length === 2) {
        textTemp += '/';
      } else {
        textTemp = textTemp[0];
      }
    }
    this.setState({text: textTemp})
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <TextInput
        keyboardType={'numeric'}
        onChangeText={this.handleChange}
        value={this.state.text}
        maxLength={5}
      />
    );
  }
```

Comment: Happy to help you. (don't forget to accept the answer or upvote)

Comment: Only small issue is there. How can I limit months for max 12? In this case, if I write 99 it still accepts

Comment: ``else if (this.state.text.length === 1) `` should be equal to two instead of one

Comment: The only problem with adding '/' after length 2 is when deleting the expiry date it keeps adding '/'

Answer (score 1):

As @AndroConsis pointed out in @Vahid Boreiri's answer, the only problem with adding '/' after length 2 is when deleting the expiry date it keeps adding '/'. To fix this, one can add a conditional backspaceFlag.

```
    const [backspaceFlag, setBackspaceFlag] = React.useState(false);
    const [expiratoinDate, setExpirationDate] = React.useState('');

    const handleExpirationDate = (text) => {
            let textTemp = text;
            if (textTemp[0] !== '1' && textTemp[0] !== '0') {
              textTemp = '';
            }
            if (textTemp.length === 2) {
              if (parseInt(textTemp.substring(0, 2)) > 12 || parseInt(textTemp.substring(0, 2)) == 0) {
                textTemp = textTemp[0];
              } else if (text.length === 2 && !backspaceFlag) {
                textTemp += '/';
                setBackspaceFlag(true);
              } else if (text.length === 2 && backspaceFlag) {
                textTemp = textTemp[0];
                setBackspaceFlag(false);
              } else {
                textTemp = textTemp[0];
              }
            }
            setExpirationDate(textTemp);
          };
```

Answer (score 0):

After searching a lot for Picker with Month/Year, for the time being i have created a logic for the Expiry date.
Hope this will help somebody.

```
const onCardExpiryDateChange = (prevValue:string, currentValue: string) => {
    if (currentValue?.includes(',') || currentValue?.includes('-') || currentValue?.includes('.')) {
        return prevValue           
    } else {
        let textTemp = currentValue
        if (textTemp[0] !== '0' && textTemp[0] !== '1' && textTemp[0] !== '2' && textTemp[0] !== '3') {
            textTemp = '';
        } else if ((prevValue?.length === 5) && currentValue.length === prevValue.length-1) {
            textTemp = textTemp?.slice(0, -3)
        } else if (textTemp.length === 6 && (textTemp[5] == '0' || textTemp[5] == '1')){
            textTemp = textTemp?.slice(0, -1)
        } 
        else if (textTemp.length === 7 && textTemp[6] == '0') {
            textTemp = textTemp?.slice(0, -1)
        } else if (textTemp.length === 2) {
            if (parseInt(textTemp?.substring(0, 2)) > 12 || parseInt(textTemp?.substring(0, 2)) == 0) {
                textTemp = textTemp?.slice(0, -1)
            } else if (textTemp?.length === 2) {
                textTemp += ' / ';
            } else {
                textTemp = textTemp[0];
            }
        }        
        return textTemp                
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`const [expiratoinDate, setExpirationDate] = useState(''); const [backspaceFlag, setBackspaceFlag] = useState(false);`

`const handleExpirationDate = (text) => {`
`if(backspaceFlag===false){`
 `if(text.length==2){ setExpirationDate(text+"/"); setBackspaceFlag(true) }`

```
`else{
  setExpirationDate(text)
}`
```

`}`

`else{`
`if(text.length==2){`
`let text2=expiratoinDate.slice(0,1)`

```
`setExpirationDate(text2);`
`setBackspaceFlag(false)
 }`

 `else{
   setExpirationDate(text)

 }`
```

`}`

```
    `};`
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

Adding an answer that resolves not being able to delete the '/' in above solution.

```
const setExpiry = (e) => {
    const { name, value } = e.target;
    var v = value;
    if (v.includes('/') == false) {
      if (v.length === 4) {
        var a = v.substr(0, 2);
        var ae = v.charAt(v.length - 2) + v.charAt(v.length - 1);
        e.target.value = a + '/' + ae;
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: Hi Jason, i tried your solution and keep getting undefined is not an object evaluating `e. target`